# How to attach a SQL Server 2005 database to a SQL Server 2012 instance

Tags: sql-server

I am facing a problem while attaching a SQL Server 2005 database to a SQL Server 2012 instance. Is there way to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: whats the error you're getting? What do you mean by **Attach**?

Comment: hi bro I got this error http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=igg46t&s=8#.UyHCNtySw0Y

Comment: Well the message appears pretty obvious. Can't you recreate the database and then import its structure and data from the original sql server 2005 instance?

Comment: +1 Crono. The message tells you how to fix: "You must re-create the database." You'll need to use SQL 2005 to either backup the database, or export as scripts.

Comment: I will try to attach it with SQL 2008 instance I think this would works

Comment: Alternatively attach to a 2008 then detach and then attach to 2012 - basically it is too old for a one step attach.

Comment: Cant remember where I read this but there was a similar question and the solution was to attach it to a 2008 Instance take a backup using 2008 and restore it on 2012.

Comment: @TomTom is it only Attach/Detach to 2008 or you need to take a backup from 2008 ??

Comment: At an attach it should upgrade the database structures, so that SHOULD be enough.

Comment: Thank you guys so now all I have to do is to attach the data base to 2008 instance then doing restore through 2012 instance

Comment: Some more info: Normally you can attach a 2005 database (internal version no 611) in a 2012 SQL Server. But the 2005 database version you've got is 603. That's a "non-release version" as it says and older than the at least required version. Probably the database was created using a pre-release beta version of SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @MicSim +10 correct the database created with beta release of SQL server  same message shows up when trying to attach it with SQL 2008 R2

Comment: I think I will use 2005 to open the data base than retrieve the structure

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may need to two-step the process. That is, build a SQL 2008 or 2008R2 instance, attach your database there, detach, then attach to your 2012 instance.